# Start a program(exe) when idle for set amount of time and then end program when no longer idle. Windows10

Tags: windows-10, code, idle

Tried to do this with task scheduler but it was a complete mess and never worked properly. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/700400/batch-how-to-run-a-program-when-the-computer-is-idle-and-stop-when-its-used ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to start program and set priority to lowest in task manager. This way, program will only use idle CPU cycles.

Comment: The program has nothing to do with CPU usage but that I simply do not want running while at the pc.